# Is there an efficient way to iterate through parent elements so i do not repeat .parent() in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Right now i am successfulling getting the value of an element by doing this:

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id').toString();
```

However, I am now finding that i am going to have to continue getting values like this and was wondering if there is a more efficient way to look through parent elements for a given element.

Below i tried this, but it does not work:

```
var id = $(this).parent(4).attr('id').toString(); ???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
 var id = $(this).closest('#idofyourelement').attr('id').toString();
```

so you justneed to specify the id of the element you are lloking and closest() will

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the
>   current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

EDIT of course if you don't know the id you can use a class

```
 var id = $(this).closest('.classOfYourElement').attr('id').toString();
```

Comment: ok, this looks good but what if i don't know the id of the element?

Comment: I suggest using something other than an `ID` for `closest`, like a `class`.  IDs should be unique, so `$('#idofyourelement')` should always work.  Also, why do you need to do `.attr('id')` if you already have the ID?  :-P

Comment: @some_bloody_fool: Use another selector, like `class` or `name`.

Comment: @some_bloody_fool you could use a class

Answer (score 1):

[`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) accepts an optional selector so you can do things like this:

```
$(this).parents('#some-ancestor')
```

and this will iterate through all parents and return elements matching `#some-ancestor`

Comment: `.closest()` is a much better recommendation than `.parents()`.  `.parents()` will look for all matches and can return more than one object.  While you could pass a selector that would only match one item, `.closest()` is more designed to get one specific parent (the closest one in the ancestor chain that matches) and it will be faster because it stops looking when it finds the first match.

Comment: @jfriend00 Good points. It's not clear if the OP only wants to get the closest element or many elements though. In the absence of more detail, I still maintain that my answer is a legitimate one.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the OP is asking for.  They want a replacement for this: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

See the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for `.closest(selector)`.  It goes up the ancestor chain (1 or more parents) until it finds a parent that matches the selector you passed.  It's usually a much better way of doing things than multiple calls to `.parent()` because it goes to the target regardless of how many intervening parents there are and will even continue to work if the number of intervening parents changes as the HTML is slightly modified.

Your code would change to this:

```
var id = $(this).closest(selector).attr('id').toString();
```

You'd have to fill in the selector to be the desired class, id or tag name or some combination of those.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.closest(selector)` or `.parents(selector)` to get to an element by a selector like

```
var id = $(this).closest(".class").attr('id').toString(); //returns the first element that finds with that class

var id = $(this).parents(".class"); //returns an array of elements with that class
```

here are the docs: [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

> **Description**: Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="4">
    <div  id="3">
        <div  id="2">
            <div id="1">
                <span>text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

The use of [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) with [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$('span').parents(':eq(2)').attr('id') // returns "3"
```

*Note: the use IDs is just for demonstration purposes*

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ugwpu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [Closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Closest will search the DOM from current DOM towards the upper root of your page (passing by all parents). so this should be enough to stop typing `parent().parent()` and just provide the selector for your desired root element.